# Data and model blocks in JAGS

Tags: jags

I am trying to model a function of observed data in JAGS. For example

```
   x[i,t]/phi ~ dpois(mu)
```

where x is observed and phi is a parameter in the model. I can't seem to get this working and am wondering if I may be missing some larger issue in JAGS.  I am pretty sure you can't have any transformation of the data in the model statement and need to use a data block but that doesn't seem to be dynamic, thus not allowing for me to fit phi.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the formulas for your model?

Comment: it is a pretty convoluted model and I think it will complicate the question.  Is my question unclear?

Comment: I believe you cannot fit the model that you have described: to my knowledge in JAGS you are not able to scale a distribution. What distribution $\phi$ is supposed to follow? If it is simple enough, you can derive the distribution of $x$ directly and sample from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here the answer from the comment:

I believe there is no way to directly sample from a scaled distribution in JAGS, except the cases where the scaled distribution can be expressed as a standard distribution.

This being said there is trick, the so called ["zero trick"](http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/BUGS/Manuals/Tricks.html#SpecifyingANewSamplingDistribution), but I have not used it so far. It might be useful in your case...